Green screen when doing a network streaming with gstreamer on iMX8
I try to implement a network stream from a Raspberry Pi to a iMX8 platform by using the NXP VPU plugins to decode the stream but the NXP side is showing a green screen with the following output:
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.178.64 port=5004  ! queue ! h264parse ! vpudec ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
====== VPUDEC: 4.7.2 build on Sep  1 2022 09:49:28. ======
        wrapper: 3.0.0 (VPUWRAPPER_ARM64_LINUX Build on Aug 31 2022 01:28:14)
        vpulib: 1.1.1
        firmware: 1.1.1.65535
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
Redistribute latency...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: cabac_init_idc
ERROR: SLICE_HEADER
ERROR: disable_deblocking_filter_idc

I use the following pipelines:
Raspberry Pi (Sender)
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true bitrate=500 threads=2 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=5004

iMX8 (Receiver)
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=<IP Sender> port=5004 ! queue ! h264parse ! vpudec ! imxvideoconvert_g2d ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?
